# Editing a file without it being executable

Tags: sed, files, permissions, directory

I have a file `secretinfo.txt` inside a directory `SensitiveData` that I am trying to edit.

Currently, the directory and file have the following permissions:

```
drwx------ 2 www-data root 4096 Apr 20 17:39 SensitiveData
-rw------- 1 www-data root 28 Apr 20 17:20 secretinfo.txt
```

The file and directory are on a UbuntuVM running an apache web server that is vulnerable to command injection attacks (it is my personal VM that I am practicing on)
I am able to inject the command `cat /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt` which outputs `My bank account pin is 4565`. I am attempted to alter the pin using the same command injection techniques but I am coming up unsuccessful. So far I have tried the following command and it does not change the text file:

```
sed -i ‘s/4565/1111/’ /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt
cat /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt | sed -i ‘s/4565/1111/’ > /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt
```

Am I missing something here when using sed or should another command be used to replace the text?
The first command does nothing while the 2nd command overwrites and creates a blank file.

Comment: As what user are you running these commands?

Comment: Its a simulated command injection "attack". I enter the commands in a text box in an apache2 webserver so I assume its running as the www-http users (which is the Apach2 Process user)

Comment: @AndyDalton Apache generally starts as root and switches to an unprivileged user so as to serve web pages. Since the `cat` command succeeds, we can assume that Apache is running as the `www-data` user, which is the only one (besides root) that can read and write the file.

Comment: It really depends on what the injection is doing.  Things like `|` and `>` are shell operators.  If the injection isn't running a shell, then there's nothing to process those operators.

Comment: Correct whenever I inject the commands it runs as the `www-data` user.

Comment: @Andy OP triggered the execution of a full multi-word command (`cat .../secretinfo.txt`) so we can safely assume that the injected command is executed by a `system()` or `popen()` call, or anything similar that invokes a shell. Nonetheless we must assume that the shell is the most basic one (`/bin/sh`) and bashisms must be avoided. BTW, we can also assume from the `cat` command that the full path of commands can be omitted for regular commands in /bin and /usr/bin (and only those). Giving the full path would be preferable anyway, unless the space for the injected command is limited.

Comment: @xhienne we can make lots of assumptions, or we can ask questions and (maybe) find a definitive answer.  Just because `cat foo` worked does not mean it _must_ have been `system()` or the like.  There could easily exist a function that parses a string and invokes something in the `exec` family directly.

Comment: @AndyDalton You are missing the point: this is all about command injection, i.e. someone provided a data with a command hidden in it, like e.g. `name=John$(cat foo)Doe`. The server-side then built a command with that data and executed it without any precaution regarding side-effects and cat was executed **inadvertently**. My assumptions are safe assumptions i.e. inferences. What you are suggesting is that the server is parsing the data, looking for a command and when one is found, the server parses it and executes it while adding the missing path to the cat command: this is pure nonsense.

Comment: @xhienne no, I do understand the point.  You presume that the server code with the security vulnerability _must_ be using some function that runs the command through a shell.  My point is, the code with the security vulnerability _could have_ used something in the `exec()` family, it is not the case that it _must be_ something like `system()`.  Based on the comments in the answer below, it does seem that it did happen to be using something that ran the command through a shell, but that was certainly not a guarantee.

Comment: @Andy The point is that a command injection, like any injection (be it SQL, HTML, etc) necessarily involves an interpreter: a shell interpreter (`/bin/sh`) in this particular case. The exec() functions do not involve an interpreter, so they are immune to command injection (unless of course you exec('/bin/sh', '-c', ...) which is what system() and popen() do under the hood, but that's not what you are suggesting). Take the time to think about it: take my example `name=John$(cat foo)Doe` and try to figure out how to trigger the command injection with exec() without involving a shell interpreter.

Comment: @xhienne Yes, you're right, I did miss the point.  I was thinking in terms of a buffer overflow attack, but the OP clearly said and you reiterated that it's a command injection attack. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Your file `secretinfo.txt` is 81 characters long. When you `cat` its content, only a small part of it is displayed.

One reason might be that there are several strings `4565` in it, and you are substituting one that is hidden, not the one that is displayed. Thus, try to substitute all possible strings, not just the first of each line:

```
sed -i ‘s/4565/1111/g’ /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt
```

Another reason might be that there are invisible characters between the one that are displayed. Try the `hd` (`hexdump`) command to figure out the exact content of the `secretinfo.txt` file. Only then will you be able to construct a relevant `sed` command.

BTW, don't do this:

```
cat /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt | sed -i ‘s/4565/1111/’ > /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt
```

First, you are reading a file while modifying it (this might work under certain conditions but consider this is not under your control and avoid this construct).

Second, the `-i` option requires that a file be given as an argument and the command produces not output, so your redirection is just emptying the file.

Comment: Sorry something occurred when I uploaded and changed permissions to the file on my VM. I fixed it and it now only shows 28 characters so there are no hidden characters. However the command `sed -i ‘s/4565/1111/g’ /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt` still does not work.

Comment: By using the same injection attack, try to get the content of `sed --help` and see 1. if that works (can sed be found in PATH? else provide the full path) and 2. if sed supports the -i option

Comment: I was able to get the output of `sed --help` `Usage: sed [OPTION]... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]... -n` is the start of the output. -i is listed as well `when processing in place -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX] edit files in place`

Comment: Good, your sed command should work. Before using sed, I suggest an `hd` dump even if you are certain of the file content. Also, try using sed without -i and examine the output closely.

Comment: So when I run it without the `-i` it just outputs the original contents of the file it does not replace anything.

Comment: Store that output in a file and take a close look to it (`hd` again). Also, use this file to test your sed command on the command line (without resorting to injection). If it works on the command line, but it no longer works when injected, maybe the injected command is modified in some way?

Comment: I got it! Thanks for all of your helping. Something whenever I was copying and pasting the command from Word was messing up the tick marks. `sed -i ‘s/4565/1111/g’ /var/SensitiveData/secretinfo.txt` vs `sed -i 's/$1,00,000/$2,00,000/' /var/confidential/bankinfo.txt` (the second one worked) Cheers mate! Thanks for working through this with me

Comment: @Jav_Py Oh, good catch! I copy-pasted your command in my answer and I completely missed that the single quotes were wrong. Glad I could help, anyway.